# Node.js server crashes after MySQL connection ends

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a Node.js server that is hosting my webpage. I have recently set up a MySQL server and created a connection to the server. When accessing a certain page, it queries the SQL database.

My problem is that if I query the DB, it makes the connection just fine, but it will crash a little later when the server automatically closes the connection. I then tried to use con.end() after the query, but this crashes the second I access the DB. It throws the error below:

```
    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/home/pi/Documents/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:203:16)
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/pi/Documents/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:138:13)
    at Connection.query (/home/pi/Documents/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:200:25)
    at Handshake.con.connect (/home/pi/Documents/PageDB.js:26:9)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/home/pi/Documents/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
    at Handshake._callback (/home/pi/Documents/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:468:16)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/home/pi/Documents/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Handshake.Sequence.OkPacket (/home/pi/Documents/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:92:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/pi/Documents/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (/home/pi/Documents/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12) code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT', fatal: false }
Close the database connection.
```

It seems to me that this is caused by the query executing after the con.end() runs. Can someone help me figure out a way to call the end function after the callback has returned with the SQL query data? Or otherwise, have my web server not crash when the connection to the DB is closed automatically? I'm open to either one. Thanks!

Code for the Node.js server is below:

```
//Create a connection to the db
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'test',
  password: 'test',
  database: 'test',
});

router.get('/products',(req,res)=>{
  con.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
      console.log('Error relating to connection: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');

    con.query('SELECT * FROM ProductList',(err,rows,fields)=>{
      if(!err)
        res.send(rows);
      else
        console.log(err);
    })
  });
  con.end(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('error:' + err.message);
  }
  console.log('Close the database connection.');
  });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node JS mysql database disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385833/node-js-mysql-database-disconnect)

Comment: Is there a canonical "node.js is asynchronous" question and answer? In this case `con.end` runs before con.connect's callback. So, boom!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're `con.end` is being called right after you `connect` method. As JS is asynchronous, so it will not wait for `connect` to end and then continue to `end` instead it will call `connect` and put the callback on the `event queue` and continue to next statement where you are closing your connection. So, what you should do is move your `end` statement inside the callback. Try using the following code

```
//Create a connection to the db
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'test',
    password: 'test',
    database: 'test',
});

router.get('/products', (req, res) => {
    con.connect((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error relating to connection: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Connection established');

        con.query('SELECT * FROM ProductList', (err, rows, fields) => {
            if (!err) {
                res.send(rows);
                con.end(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.log('error:' + err.message);
                    }
                    console.log('Close the database connection.');
                });
            } else
                console.log(err);
        })
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! And now that you've explained it, I get why. Thanks again