# Connection closing frequently with mysql nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Node.js is closing connection frequently with MySQL. This occurs every 2-4 hours interval. How can I stop this happening?

```
{ Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/home/zubizi/retech_node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/zubizi/retech_node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/zubizi/retech_node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1085:12)
    at args.(anonymous function) (/home/zubizi/.nvm/versions/node/v11.2.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/event-loop-inspector/index.js:138:29)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' }
```

I used [Node JS mysql database disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385833/node-js-mysql-database-disconnect) this solution but still cannot query MySql.

I used following code to keep connection alive:

```
// keep connection alive 
setInterval(function () {
    conn.query('SELECT 1');
    console.log('Keep alive the connection.');
}, 30000);
```

But it is not affecting anything.
why is it happening?

Comment: If it is disconnecting due to network issues then you will need to implement logic to reconnect when it happens.

Comment: Why are you holding connections open for so long? I'm thinking you may be better off with connection pooling. If you're using the `mysql` npm module, [details here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections). Also, rather than a `query("SELECT 1")`, use [`ping`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#ping).

Comment: No, it is not due to the network issue!! I am using the local MySQL server

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have a little problem with switching database.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142512/switch-database-in-a-connection-pool-in-nodejs-mysql

Comment: @HelloWorld - That doesn't explain why you're holding connections open for so long. (See also my answer there.)